# no /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu file found in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: sound, themes

After installing Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I wanted the log-in theme sound to play.  When searching for the /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu file, it did not find it.  The Ubuntu Theme Sounds I think as supposed to be installed as the default sound theme, but I can't find it, or it does not exist.  I read somewhere that this file can be recreated, but I don't know how to do this.  Is there a way to download and install the default ubuntu theme sounds correctly, so I can use them.  I downloaded the Smooth Theme and I can click on the different sounds in that file and they play.  I have used (paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg) in the Startup Applications Peferrences, along with others but nothing works.  My sound system is all working, it just doesn't find the /sounds/ubuntu/stereo/ file. Any help would be most appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: To be clear you did an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04?

Comment: Yes I did an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.  I do have a dual boot system with 20.04 and Windows 10.  When I place /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu into the terminal I get bash: usr/share/sounds/ubuntu: Is a directory.  Am I doing something wrong in finding this file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to (re)install two ([1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/ubuntu-sounds/filelist), [2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/ubuntu-touch-sounds/filelist)) packages with sound files placed in the `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu` folder by:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-sounds ubuntu-touch-sounds
```

Comment: Where are the files located after I do this, and how to I find that they are there?

Comment: When I go to the files directory > Other Locations > usr > share > sounds > ubuntu > stereo I find the list of all the .ogg tones, but they are grayed out.  It looks like they are there but not usable.  Do I need to create a new folder by clicking on the "Create Folder" botton in the right upper corner?

Comment: I might add, I downloaded this file "ubuntu-sounds_0.13_all.deb" from Ubuntu Software to my download file.  When I right clicked on this file I selected "Move to" and then the "Select Move Destinationi" box opens. From there I went to Other Location > Computer > usr > share > sounds > ubuntu > stereo and that's where I find the grayed out files.

Comment: You have to simply run the command in the above answer. DO NOT create or remove objects manually in/from the APT-controlled directories!

Comment: I did find the sound files I could double click on and play.  When I start my computer I don’t have it setup with the login screen.  It just opens to the desktop.  How would I change the above command to play a sound when the desktop screen opens?  I don’t know if this can be done or what the command would need to be.  Maybe that I don’t have a login screen the above command doesn’t work.  Is there anyway to do this?